# Uncheck checkbox in React pop up

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, bootstrap-modal

I want to uncheck all the checkboxes everytime the popup shows. Have written a function for it which it getting called on click of the popup show button but the previously checked checkboxes are still remaining checked. In the popup i have ul with li's that are generated by mapping.

My function is:

```
clearList() {
    var list_items = document.getElementById("bucket-list").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i=0; i<list_items.length; i++) {
      list_items[i].getElementsByTagName("input").checked = false;
    }
  }
```

Inside render function:

```
<ul id="bucket-list">
              {this.state.buckets.map(function (bucket, i) {
                return (
                <li key={i}>
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={bucket.id}
                    refs="status_changed"
                    onChange={self.onCheckUncheck.bind(self, "status_changed")} />
                  <label>{bucket.name}</label>
                </li>
                )
              })}
              </ul>
```

Comment: why are you not doing it the react way?

Comment: can you please elaborate? you mean update the checked status the react way?

Comment: yes I mean why aren't you using the checkbox as a controlled component, I can provide an answer but it will be slightly different, that's why i'm asking

Comment: Yes please. I'm willing to modify as required.

Answer (score 0):

well since you are buckets array to provide the checkbox props then you can add the you can add the `checked` property to this array, and whenever you want to clear, you only modify this property to `false`,
for your convenience use some `checkbox` library such as `react-icheck`, install it using `npm install --save react-icheck` for instance,
import it to your file : `import {Checkbox} from 'react-icheck'`
now add the `checked` prop to your `buckets` array, `checked:false` ,
and replace your code with something similar:

```
         <ul>
          {this.state.buckets.map(function (bucket, i) {
            return (
            <li key={i}>
              <Checkbox
                increaseArea="20%"
                label={bucket.name}
                name={bucket.id}
                onChange={this.handleBucketCheckChange}
                checked={bucket.checked}/>
            </li>
            )
          })}
          </ul>
```

and to clear the checkboxes:

```
clearList() {
 let localBucketsArray = [...this.state.buckets];

 map(localBucketsArray, function(bucket,key){
  bucket.checked = false;
 })

  this.setState({buckets: localBuckets})
  }
```